# minimal dominant weight and cosets of root lattice

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

This is a question about abstract root system, root lattice and weight lattice. Most definitions are standard as in Wikipedia or Humphreys' Lie algebra, section 13.

> If $\Phi$ is an irreducible root system in $\mathbb{R}^l$, $\Delta$ a base, $\Lambda$ the weight lattice, and $\Lambda_r$ the root lattice of $\Phi$ w.r.t $\Delta$. Prove that each coset of $\Lambda$ in $\Lambda_r$ contains unique minimal dominant weight.

---

**Definitions:**

Let $\Phi$ be a root system in $E=\mathbb{R}^l$, with a base $\Delta=\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_l\}$.

Let $(-,-)$ denote positive definite inner product on $E$, and $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle:=\frac{2(\alpha,\beta)}{(\beta,\beta)}$.

A vector $\lambda\in E$ is called a **weight** if $\langle \lambda,\alpha\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $\alpha\in\Delta$ (or equivalently all $\alpha\in\Phi$).

A weight $\lambda$ is called **dominant** if $\langle\lambda,\alpha\rangle\geq 0$ for all $\alpha\in\Phi$. (These are precisely weights lying in 
Fundamental Weyl chamber w.r.t. $\Delta$.

The weights in $E$ w.r.t. $\Phi$ form a lattice of rank$=l=\dim E$; called weight lattice.

The lattice $\Lambda:=\mathbb{Z}\alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathbb{Z}\alpha_l$ is called root lattice. It is known that $[\Lambda:\Lambda_r]$ is finite.

On $\Lambda$, define partial order: $\lambda,\mu\in \Lambda$, say $\lambda\prec\mu$ if $\mu-\lambda$ is non-negative $\mathbb{R}$-combination of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_l$.

A weight $\lambda\in\Lambda$ is called **minimal dominant weight** if it is a dominant weight (i.e. lies in fund. Weyl chamber) and it is minimal w.r.t. ordering $\prec$, i.e. if $\mu$ is a dominant weight s.t. $\mu\prec\lambda$ then $\mu=\lambda$.

The problem is that each coset $\lambda+\Lambda_r$ of root lattice in wight lattice contains unique minimal dominant weight.

Comment: Fairly sure I worked this out 30 years ago. If only I could remember how I did it.

Comment: The existence is fairly obvious: each coset is stable under the action of Weyl group. For the uniqueness, note that the difference of two distinct minimal dominant weights is a sum of simple roots with integer coefficients, which contains at least one positive and at least one negative integer. Now consider the weight which is smaller than the two minimal dominant weights, given by the above equation. Then this weight is dominant and we have a contradiction.